# Prevent Caching of PDFs in ASP Classic

Tags: pdf, caching, asp-classic

I just started to manage a website for the company I work for and it is still running with ASP Classic so I have had to learn quite a bit.

Recently our managment has started to post a dynamically updated PDF to the website every few hours.

The problem I have been experiencing is that some users who access the file are now getting old cached versions of them despite changing headers to prevent this.

So in my search for a solution for this I came across this Stack Overflow post 
[Right way to have asp.net not cache pdf files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8233670/right-way-to-have-asp-net-iis-not-cache-pdf-files)

But it was written for ASP.NET and not ASP Classic but I was able to come up with a solution using VBScript that works thanks to that post and thought I should share it with others.

Comment: Couple of things... **1.** Using client-side code to generate this is overkill **2** Using client-side VBScript is only available in versions of Internet Explorer browser *(infact even Microsoft don't support it in IE 11 running in Edge mode, what does that tell you!)*. **3** Disabling code through noscript etc will render this solution useless.

Comment: If you have access to the dynamically updated PDF *(I assume through Classic ASP using some ActiveX component like Persits.PDF for example)* then you should be using HTTP headers to control the caching from the server to the browser. If it doesn't work then you are doing it wrong or the browser *(which I assume is IE)* is overriding the `no-cache` request in which case appending a random string works well.

Comment: Modifying the headers does not work for all the clients that access this file additionally our company is extremely restricted to our browsers we are still using IE9 across the board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below generates a link with the current time converted to a Double so it produces a random link each time the page is loaded to trick the browser into thinking it is a new pdf.

```
<a href="yourpdffile.pdf?<%= CStr(CDbl(Now)) %>">Link to the PDF</a>
```

- Now is the current time
- `CDbl(Now)` Converts the current time into a Double
- `CStr(CDbl(Now))` Converts the Double into a string

Comment: Why are you doing that client-side? If you generate the link in Classic ASP *(server-side)* just do something like; `<a href="yourpdffile.pdf?<%= CStr(CDbl(Now)) %>">Link to the PDF</a>`. That way the link will already be generated from the server response without relying on client-side code.

Comment: I had tried that originally but it did not work so I might have miss typed something when input it because it now works I will alter my answer to include your comments